# My upgrade to Lubuntu 18.04 from lubuntu17.04 on Acer Aspire Es-533 failed

Tags: grub2

My upgrade to Lubuntu 18.04 from 17.04 on Acer Aspire Es-533 failed because package grub 2. My p.c works with dual boot linux- windows 10.  In the beginning I have installed lubuntu 17.04 in my system and I had a grub 2 problem which have been fixed. Then I installed windows 10 and the dual boot worked very well until I decided to install lubuntu 18.04 instead of lubuntu 17.04. The installation went well until the setup of grub2 package. I didn't receive any error message but  my system blocked. But using the command /sudo ubiquity b/ the installation run well. Actually I can boot only on windows 10 or on the lubuntu 18.04 live usb. When I plug out the iso usbm and choose to boot on my linux I had error message on the screen /Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported..For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions./Can these details help any one to fix my problem? I really Hope so.

Comment: In fact i tried to install lubuntu 18.04 in stead of the old lubuntu 17.04 using iso live usb.

Comment: Did you verify the download (of 18.04 ISO), check integrity of media?  before attempt to 're-install/upgrade'. You'll have to provide more information as to what your error messages, or problems are (*and detailed*), as currently we have only background and a note it "failed".